# Conditional UPDATE statement using a JOIN on two tables

Tags: sql-server

I am trying to conditionally update a structure table joined to a contract table where there are different permit types that need to be updated. I have included 2 as an example, but I have 10 to update:

```
update structure set
  structure_item_cost = case when (contract_lut_contract_status_id in 
      (17,16) and structure_lut_permit_type_id = 6) then 2500
    else
    case when (contract_lut_contract_status_id in (17,16) and 
      structure_lut_permit_type_id = 17) then 5000
    end
FROM structure
join contract on contract_interest_id = structure_interest_id
```

I want the structure item cost to update based upon the two criteria:
`contract_lut_contract_status_id in (17,16)`
and then on the different condition `where structure_lut_permit_type_id = 17`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

just remove the else case

```
update structure
set structure_item_cost = case 
                              when (contract_lut_contract_status_id in 
(17,16) and structure_lut_permit_type_id = 6) then 2500
                              when (contract_lut_contract_status_id in (17,16) and 
structure_lut_permit_type_id = 17) then 5000 end
FROM structure join contract on contract_interest_id = structure_interest_id
```

or add another end to the case statement

```
update structure
set structure_item_cost = case when (contract_lut_contract_status_id in 
  (17,16) and structure_lut_permit_type_id = 6) then 2500
else
case when (contract_lut_contract_status_id in (17,16) and 
  structure_lut_permit_type_id = 17) then 5000
end end
FROM structure join contract on contract_interest_id = structure_interest_id
```

Comment: Its better to add Else condition to avoid any null values in the Update